# How to create Reset Password token and send email with Mail instead of Notifications?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have an Email controller in which I'm preparing all email to be sent.

When I send an email, I usually use a method like:

```
class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function messageReceived(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'email:rfc,dns',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);
        Mail::to('john.doe@foo.com')->send(
            new MessageReceived(
                $request->email,
                $request->body
            )
        );
    }
}
```

For the reset password email I'm currently using, I have add the following method to this class:

```
public function resetPassword(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email|exists:myconnection.users,email']);

    $status = Password::broker('users:myconnection')->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

    return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
        ? response()->json(['status' => __($status)])
        : response()->json(['email' => __($status)]);
}
```

How to create the token and send the notifiation with `Mail::to()->send()` instead of `sendResetLink()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually generate a password reset token through Laravel's `Password` facade.

```php
// populate user
$user = User::whereEmail($request->email)->first();

// generate token
$token = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::getRepository()->create($user);
```

You can then pass the token to a custom mailer.

```php
$data = [
    'token' => $token,
    // ...
];

Mail::to($user)->send(new PasswordResetMailer($data));
```

---

In response to your comments:

You can set a custom broker during token generation.

```php
$token = Password::broker('your_custom_broker')->getRepository()->create($user);
```

Comment: Thanks! That works... almost! But it's populating the wrong `password_resets` table, how should I set the broker to fill the good one?

Comment: I'm not extending the Auth scaffolding... how to do so ?

Comment: You did not post a full controller, so I'm not exactly sure what you have available.  Are you including traits `use ResetsPasswords;` or `use SendsPasswordResetEmails;`?

Comment: My controller just extends `Controller`, I have updated my question to show the class. I'm not including any trait. I feel that I should add `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;`

Comment: See further edits. I tested and it works on my end.

Comment: That works indeed, thanks a lot. I didn't try it at first because Intelephense says `Undefined method 'getRepository'.` in vscode.